# does Beautiful Soup find_all() returns an ordered list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The data returned by the `find_all()` method has class of `bs4.element.ResultSet`, and according to my research is a sub-class of lists, so assuming it is an ordered, but I still want to ask to make sure  my assumption is right, since I very beginner in programming, I don't want to trust myself too much and documentation doesn't really state that it is an ordered but in honesty I just scanned it not fully read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is may not a list in the sense of an ordered list, the entries are in the order in which they are found in the tree, their natural nesting order.

If the elements you are selecting in the tree are "ordered", so is the list.

Comment: thanks, this is somehow make me trustful in using `find_all()` than going back and forth in the tree